# Basic question: When to use the imaginary symbol in quadratics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I know that my question is basic but I would like to know when to add the imaginary symbol in and answer after rooting it?

Sometimes, I see answer with the $\pm$ before the root symbol (or not) and sometimes it is before a number ($ab$ and $i$ as imaginary).

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is a common confusion. I suspect there is an answer on this site, but can't find it. Please [edit] the question to show us a few _particular_ examples where you see or don't see the $\pm$ and are puzzled. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that you are trying to find all values $~x_0,~$ either real or complex, such that $~x_0~$ is a root of the following equation:

$$Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0 ~: ~A,B,C \in \Bbb{R}, ~A \neq 0. \tag1 $$

Before attacking (1) above, it is important to focus on preliminary considerations.

---

There is no real number $~x~$ such that $~x^2 = -1.~$  So, Mathematicians **arbitrarily** decided to let the **symbol** $~i~$ refer to the imaginary number represented by $~\displaystyle \sqrt{-1}.~$

Further, for any non-negative real number $~D,~$ you have that $~\displaystyle \left[ ~\sqrt{D} ~\right]^2 = D.~$

So, Mathematicians decided to extend this idea so that
$~\displaystyle \left[ ~\sqrt{-1} ~\right]^2 = -1.~$

This implies that $~\displaystyle i^2 = \left[ ~\sqrt{-1} ~\right]^2 = -1.$

Now, when Mathematicians refer to a complex number, they are referring to a number that has form $ ~(R + iS)~$ where $~R,S~$ are any real numbers, and $~i~$ symbolizes $~\displaystyle \sqrt{-1}.$

Then, if you have a complex number of the form $~(R + iS),~$ then :

- If $~R~$ happens to equal $~0,~$ then you have the  *purely imaginary number* $~(iS).$
- If $~S~$ happens to equal $~0,~$ then you have the *purely real number* $~(R).$

---

Further, you have that

$$(-i)^2 = (-1 \times i)^2 = (-1)^2 \times \left(i^2\right)$$

$$= 1 \times \left(i^2\right) = 1 \times (-1) = -1.$$

So, you have two complex numbers, $~[ ~0 + (i \times 1)~] ~$ and $~[ ~0 + (i \times -1) ~] ~$ that each satisfy the equation $~x^2 = -1.$

This means that the equation

$$~x^2 = -1 ~$$

has the two roots $~x = \pm i.$

---

Furthermore, for any positive real number $~D,~$ consider the following two equations:

- $x^2 = D.$ 
  Since $~D~$ is assumed positive, the value $~\sqrt{D}~$ is defined, and is also a positive number.  Then, the two roots of the equation will be given by $~x = \pm \sqrt{D}.~$ 
  For example, if $~D = 4,~$ then the equation $~x^2 = 4~$ has the two roots $~x = \pm 2.$
- $x^2 = -D.$ 
  This is more complicated. 
  $\displaystyle x^2 = -D \implies x^2 = [ ~(-1) \times D~].$ 
  One solution will be $\displaystyle ~\left[ ~i \times \sqrt{D}~\right],~$ 
  since $\displaystyle ~\left[ ~i \times \sqrt{D}~\right]^2 = [~i^2 \times D ~] = (-1) \times D = -D.$
  Then, a second solution will be 
  $\displaystyle ~\left[ ~(-1) \times i \times \sqrt{D} ~\right] = \left[ ~-i\sqrt{D} ~\right],$ 
  Since $\displaystyle ~\left[ ~(-1) \times i \times \sqrt{D} ~\right]^2 = (-1)^2 \times ~\left[ ~i \times \sqrt{D} ~\right]^2 = ~\left[ ~i \times \sqrt{D} ~\right]^2 = -D.$ 
  So, when $~D~$ is positive, the equation $~x^2 = -D~$ 
  will have the two roots $~\displaystyle x = \pm i\sqrt{D}.$ 
  For example, if $~D = 4,~$ then the equation $~x^2 = -4,~$ 
  will have the two roots $~x = \pm (i \times 2).$

---

Now, the equation in (1) above can be attacked.

$$Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0 ~: ~A,B,C \in \Bbb{R}, ~A \neq 0 \iff $$

$$x^2 + \frac{B}{A} ~x   + \frac{C}{A} = 0. \tag2 $$

Note that

$$\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right)^2 = x^2 + \frac{B}{A} ~x + \frac{B^2}{4A^2}.$$

This implies that equation (2) above can be re-expressed as

$$\left[ ~\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right)^2 - \frac{B^2}{4A^2} ~\right] + \frac{C}{A} = 0. \tag3 $$

Equation (3) above can be re-expressed as

$$\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right)^2 - \frac{B^2 - 4AC}{4A^2} = 0. \tag4 $$

What this signifies is that any value of $~x,~$ real or complex, will satisfy equation (1) above if and only if it satisfies equation (4) above.

Equation (4) above may be re-expressed as

$$\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right)^2 = \frac{B^2 - 4AC}{4A^2}.$$

Now, let $~D~$ denote $~\displaystyle \frac{B^2 - 4AC}{4A^2}.~$

Either $~D = 0~$ or $~D > 0,~$ or $~D < 0.$

If $~D = 0,~$ then you have the equation

$$\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right)^2 = 0. \tag5 $$

This equation will only have one root, namely

$$\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right) = 0 \iff x = \frac{-B}{2A}.$$

If $~D > 0,~$ then you have the equation

$$\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right)^2 = D. \tag6 $$

From the preliminary discussion, this equation will have the two roots:

$$\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right) = \pm \sqrt{D} \iff x = \frac{-B}{2A} \pm \sqrt{D}. \tag7 $$

If $~D < 0,~$ then let $~E~$ denote $~|D|.~$ 
This implies that $~E > 0,~$ and that $~D = -E.~$

Then you have the equation

$$\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right)^2 = -E. \tag8 $$

From the preliminary discussion, this equation will have the two roots:

$$\left( ~x + \frac{B}{2A} ~\right) = \pm i\sqrt{E} \iff x = \frac{-B}{2A} \pm i\sqrt{E}. \tag9 $$